# jquery hide nearest row on click

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, haml

i used to be able to use the below code to hide a row when a user clicked delete, for what reason this has stopped working

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.deleteRecord').live( function() {
        if(confirm("Are you sure?")){
            $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut();
        }
    });
});
```

haml line

```
\#{link_to image_tag('/img/icons/packs/diagona/16x16/101.png', :border => 0), schedule, :method => :delete, :remote=>true, :class=>'deleteRecord'}
```

this is what i have within my application.js, and all other events seem to be working or triggering, minus this

```
//= require jquery
//= require rails
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require best_in_place
//= require plugins

//= require messages
//= require_self


$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".best_in_place").best_in_place();
    $('.best_in_place').bind("ajax:success", function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').effect("pulsate", { times:3 }, 500);
    });

});


$(window).load(function () {
    $('#tab-panel-1').createTabs();
    $('#dataTable').dataTable(
        {
            "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
            "aaSorting": [[ 4, "desc" ]]
        }
    );
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.deleteRecord').on('click', function() {
        if(confirm("Are you sure?")){
            $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut();
        }
    });

    $('#notice').effect("pulsate", { times:3 }, 500);



});
```

Comment: Besides your question, make sure that you really need .live() it will also bind for future elements and should be only used if you edit your table after binding. otherwise use .on()

Comment: **jQuery ofcial documentation** _As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()._ [link](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: The records are added after or before the document load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misuse the `live` function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.deleteRecord').live('click', function() {
        if(confirm("Are you sure?")){
            $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut();
        }
    });
});
```

And now, `live` is deprecated, so just use `on`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.deleteRecord').on('click', function() {
        if(confirm("Are you sure?")){
            $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut();
        }
    });
});
```

jQuery api [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

**EDIT**

Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().

The usage of `on` or `live` depends on your purpose.

Comment: It's true that `live` is deprecated, but your usage of `on` doesn't provide delegated event handling which is likely the reason he's using `live`.

Comment: The `on` can be used todo the same as `live` as "delegate" if he used over document. See this fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/pKzZ7/)

Comment: @JorgeLoureiro: No need to define it on document. Actually I'd rather suggest not to but rater on some *closer* container.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('img.deleteRecord').on("click", function() {
            if ( confirm("Are you sure?") ) {
                $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut();
            }
        });
    });
```

`.live()` is deprecated, [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is prefered as of jQuery 1.7+.

Also, it's not good to only search for class name, if possible use a selector like the above.

**EDIT**

If the rows are dynamically added you need to use the following:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#parent').on("click", "img.deleteRecord", function() {
            if ( confirm("Are you sure?") ) {
                $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: He's (hopefully) using `live()` for a reason which is likely that rows are being dynamically added during page lifetime. Therefore your code wouldn't work with those added elements.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik Well aware of that. Added an option if the rows are dynamically added, but still with `.on()`

Comment: rows arent being dynamically at present but will be in the future, i have tried all the above methods, still no luck, its not even triggering the event

Comment: @Paul'Whippet'McGuane Strange, could you maybe make an concise jsFiddle were there problem exists. So we could test it.

Comment: @sQVe jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lc9c5/ this seems to be working as it should, so must be something else conflicting maybe?

Comment: @Paul'Whippet'McGuane Seems to be working yes. This is more and more sounding like a reference thing or something. It really should work.

Comment: ive moved everything but the bare essentials from my application.js still no luck :S

Comment: @Paul'Whippet'McGuane: Please check that all your scripts (including libraries) are actually loaded and that you're not getting any javascript errors? Do that either Firebug or Chrome dev tools. Because this is 100% problem in your code by having some typo, missing file or similar.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik im assured they are all loading, as otherwise best_in_place etc... wouldnt working, this is meant to be just a basic  script :S

Comment: @Paul'Whippet'McGuane: Assured? But can you please check for yourself? And also check for the errors I mentioned previously.

Comment: if i use :confirm => 'Are you sure?' the alert box is triggered, is it possible from that call when the user selects yes to hide the row?

Comment: interesting if i move the code out of application.js and just put it into a `<script>` tag within my footer it all works

Answer (score -1):

***Description:** Get the first element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree.*

Begins with the current element
Travels up the DOM tree until it finds a match for the supplied selector
The returned jQuery object contains zero or one element

Source: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

**EDIT**

If you fully understood the docs try your code with Firebug console.
Frist, try with this:

```
$('.deleteRecord').eq(0).closest('tr').fadeOut();
```

If it works, try adding this onlick function to another element to see whehter it works with it, or not.

In last resort try with the confirm().